# Adding string to scraped url (scrapy)

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I have made a scraper to go thru threads in a forum and save all links posted by users. The problem is that the forum uses a "do you really want to leave the site" thing. This makes the links I scrape incomplete like so:

```
/leave.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lonestatistik.se%2Floner.asp%2Fyrke%2FUnderskoterska-1242
```

To work it would need the websites domain in the beginning of the link.

Is there a way to add it some way? Or to just scrape the target url.

```
def parse(self, response):
    next_link = response.xpath("//a[contains(., '>')]//@href").extract()[0]
    if len(next_link):
        yield self.make_requests_from_url(urljoin(response.url, next_link))

    posts = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="post_message"]')
    for post in posts:
        i = TextPostItem()
        i['url'] = post.xpath('a/@href').extract()

        yield i
```

-edit-
So, based on eLRuLL's answer I did this.

```
def parse(self, response):
    next_link = response.xpath("//a[contains(., '>')]//@href").extract()[0]
    if len(next_link):
        yield self.make_requests_from_url(urljoin(response.url, next_link))
    posts = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="post_message"]')
    for post in posts:
        i = TextPostItem()
        url = post.xpath('./a/@href').extract_first()
        i['new_url'] = urljoin(response.url, url)

        yield i
```

Which worked. Except for that I now scrape an url for every single post, even if that post didnt have a link posted.

Comment: try with your previous xpath `a/@href` instead of `./a/@href`

Comment: this is now a pure xpath problem, you need to check the correct path on your site.

Comment: Yeah, been trying stuff out. Guess i'll get it in the end. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you need to add the domain url at the beginning of that new url. You could try to use the `response.url` to append the base url to the new one, so something like:

```
from urlparse import urljoin
...
url = post.xpath('./a/@href').extract_first()
new_url = urljoin(response.url, url) # someurl.com/leave.php?...
yield Request(new_url, ...)
...
```

Comment: So basicly I replace my `i['url'] = post.xpath('a').extract()` with your code? It gave me a definition error on "Request" tho.

Comment: See my edit. I cant see why I now scrape every url of every post. But the links that are scraped are correct now!